# How to know whether Comment is replied by some user or not of youtube in Java

Tags: java, youtube

I am using Youtube api version 2 and using Java language to develop my project.

I want to fetch comment and replies associated with that comment. I do not know how to do it. I have tried all the possibilities that's written in the youtube development guide but not succeed.

Can any one give me code example how to achieve this?

Now I'm using this code to fetch the replies of that comment(hardcoded in the code)

```
    int startIndex = 1, maxResult = 50, j = 0;
    url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/6afPT1hbMLk?client=comment+research?start-index%3D1";

    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(appName);
    YouTubeQuery query =  new YouTubeQuery(new URL(url));

    try {
        CommentFeed commentFeed = service.query(query, CommentFeed.class);
    } catch (IOException | ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it give me following exception...

com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 1, Column 268] Invalid root element, expected (namespace uri:local name) of (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:feed), found (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:entry
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.throwParseException(XmlParser.java:730)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:693)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:576)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:867)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)